# Can I Include an application within another

Tags: android

I have the source code for two applications. One is a legacy official app with package name `com.officialaz.app` and one is the new application I have created with package name `com.media.mediaplayer`. The manager wants the two applications integrated so that the second app becomes part of the first one. Given the fact that both applications have manifests and activities of their own, is this possible to achieve? Or should I use intents to interact between the two applications (installed separately on the device)?  One thing that I tried was importing the source code for the 2nd app as a module within the 1st app. Then near the hammer icon I see two apps I can select from the drop-down menu. Running the app does not work and it says that e.g. `apk_6.apk` is defined multiple times. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you make the same application id for both the apps then you can make communication between two apps

Comment: you can merge both apps, but it is not as easy as just copy the code. You will have to handle some conflicts for sure, and at least - merge the manifests.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to implement this is to use "Implicit intent".

- In your legacy app, in the manifest add some custom url:
  [image]
- In your new app, add a button click event handler, and link it to open the custom url: Custom Protocol Url
- You can also pass some data to and from these two apps. A relevant, but not exactly the same tutorial can be found [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/android-handle-custom-protocol-urls/#more-4085).
- Google also has a formal [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) on this topic.

Comment: Do you mean I should add custom url and intent filters to the second app and put the button in the legacy app?

Comment: This is by far the most non intrusive way.